# Create a for loop that counts up to one variable by another in lua

Tags: variables, for-loop, lua

This is an assignment I must complete in CSP and I'm completely dumbfounded as to how to do it:

"Get two numbers from the user.  The first will be the number to count up to, the second will be the number to count by.

For example, the user gives the numbers "20" and "3"
1
4
7
10
13
16
19

Note: it didn't actually reach 20."

Comment: So whilst you say you're dumbfounded, what have you actually tried to do to solve this yourself? Have you tried searching the web for "Getting input from the user in Lua", and "Lua for loops". Have also you even attempted the first part of the question ("Get two numbers from the user") yet? If so [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40963781/edit) the question and add your code in.

Answer (score 2):

Seems pretty standard

```
for i = start, finish, increment do
    print(i)
end
```

Is a for loop, so just substitute finish and increment with the numbers and set start to 1